# Find next char boundary index in string after char

Tags: string, char, rust

Given the string `s`, and the index `i` which is where the `好` character starts:

```
let s = "abc 好 def";
let i = 4;
```

What's the best way to get the index after that character, so that I can slice the string and get `abc 好`? In code:

```
let end = find_end(s, i);
assert_eq!("abc 好", &s[0..end]);
```

(Note, `+ 1` doesn't work because that assumes that the character is only 1 byte long.)

I currently have the following:

```
fn find_end(s: &str, i: usize) -> usize {
    i + s[i..].chars().next().unwrap().len_utf8()
}
```

But I'm wondering if I'm missing something and there's a better way?

Answer (score 7):

You could use `char_indices` to get the next index rather than using `len_utf8` on the character, though that has a special case for the last character.

I would use the handy [`str::is_char_boundary()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.16.0/std/primitive.str.html#method.is_char_boundary) method.  Here's an implementation using that:

```
fn find_end(s: &str, i: usize) -> usize {
    assert!(i < s.len());
    let mut end = i+1;
    while !s.is_char_boundary(end) {
        end += 1;
    }
    end
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=a7bdfa29c0e301a6c2f8ef6f2cda61fd&version=stable&backtrace=1)

Normally I would make such a function return `Option<usize>` in case it's called with an index at the end of `s`, but for now I've just asserted.

In many cases, instead of explicitly calling `find_end` it may make sense to iterate using [`char_indices`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.16.0/std/primitive.str.html#method.char_indices), which gives you each index along with the characters; though it's slightly annoying if you want to know the end of the current character.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I didn't include it in the question, but I also had `is_char_boundary` at some point. With `char_indices`, if you stop at a char and want to get the next index, you can use `i + c.len_utf8()`, so that's a good idea too!

Answer (score 1):

To serve as a complement to @ChrisEmerson's answer, this is how one could implement a `find_end` that searches for the end of a character's first occurrence. [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=631187c142f48a5b2806f1f50a5c732c&version=stable&backtrace=0)

```
fn find_end<'s>(s: &'s str, p: char) -> Option<usize> {
    let mut indices = s.char_indices();
    let mut found = false;
    for (_, v) in &mut indices {
        if v == p {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if found {
        Some(indices.next()
                    .map_or_else(|| s.len(), |(i, _)| i))
    } else {
        None
    }
}
```

Although it avoids the byte boundary loop, it is still not very elegant. Ideally, an iterator method for traversing until a predicate is met would simplify this.

Comment: I'm a bit surprised there doesn't seem to be a `next_char_boundary` method!

Comment: Thanks as well! The downside with using `next()` is that it only works if there is another character after the current one.

Comment: @ChrisEmerson Yes, a `next_char_boundary` method would be perfect.

Comment: @robinst Characters at the end can be addressed easily. I've updated the function.